# .NET Core 2.2 with Identity Server 4 SameSite Cookie Changes Issue

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a Single page web application with consists of the following

1. Angular 8 Front End
2. .Net Core Web Api Back End
3. .Net Core Identity Server Authentication Server

I recently started to see a few warnings in my console which reads - "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at "" was set without the 'SameSite' attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with 'SameSite=None' and 'Secure'.

So based upon this a did a little bit of research and landed on the following article, which happens to explain everything that is going on in detail.
[Explanation of Cookie Issue](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/)

I read the article over several times and think I have a grasp of it, but still I am struggling on one simple aspect of it. There is a few areas where they ask you to add some code to your "Project".  My question is (being still somewhat of a newbie with Identity Server and its inner workings), is what is the "Project" they are referring to. I am not exactly sure where to put the code they provide in order to fix the issue.

1. For me its not so obvious on where exactly to put the provided code.  I have 2 Visual Studio solutions - one representing my authentication server (Identity Server) and one for my Web Api.  Which of these solutions' Startup.cs files do I add the code solution?
2. If I add it to my Identity Server project, my confusion is that I am not using any "Cookie Based Authentication" so there exists nowhere in my identity server project which I have a place that sets a cookie and I know part of the solution, mentioned in the article, is to add a cookie which is both "Secure" and is set to "Same-Site=None".  Where in the project do I create this type of cookie?
3. One more thing I did notice is that once the cookies are set they are not being deleted when a logout is performed.

Keep in mind that these issues are only occuring on a MacOS running Google Chrome. If I run my application on a Windows PC, I still see the warnings, but I am able to log out and clear all existing cookies

Comment: I agree with you, the documentation for an Angular,Web Api solution is poor for a newbie to 3rd party Authentication providers.  I have not yet been able to get Angular 9 and Asp.net core to work.

Answer (score 2):

You will get below console warring in Google Chrome and your Identity server failed to redirect to Client that could be React App or Angular App for Chrome version 80.

A cookie associated with a resource at was set with SameSite=None but without Secure. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked SameSite=None if they are also marked Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

To Fix this , you need to do changes mention in below link -

https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/

NOTE : For .Net Core 2.2 , set SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1) , For .Net Core 3.0 or above , set SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified

Also , for Chrome 80 version , add this extra condition -

```
 if ( userAgent.Contains("Chrome/8"))
            {
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer will always create cookie when you login.
You can read more here - http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/signin.html

It mean identityserver use cookie to authenticated user

You can configure same site cookie as follow

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            });
```

Comment: Also note that some flows (namely ones that occur in iframes - e.g. automatic silent renew for SPAs) will not work with `Lax` and you should instead use `None`. Then also note that `None` is not supported by some older browsers that then default to `Strict`. To complicate matters further as of Chrome 80 any cookie without SameSite defined will be treated as `Lax` by default. To to further complicate things - to explicitly set SameSite=None on ASP.Net (and Core) you need to be running the latest runtime patch.

Comment: More here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thank you for the link to the article.  So based on what I understand from the article it seems that identity server will (out of the box) without any configuration from me, deliver out a cookie automatically by default.  So in order to update the options on that default cookie they provide (set samesite mode and set secure equal to true), I would need to add your above code in my configure services method in the Startup.cs file of my Identity Server project?

Comment: Currently the only line I have related to authentication in my "ConfigureServices" method is the following:
`services.AddAuthenticationServices<IdentityServerConfigurationDbContext, IdentityServerPersistedGrantDbContext, AdminIdentityDbContext, UserIdentity, UserIdentityRole>(Environment, Configuration, Logger);`

Do I need to add to this code or also add your code.  Will adding your code snippet interfere with what I already have set for authentication?

Comment: I dont think it will be intefere.  
note that identityserver have its  cookie - IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme  
I have not use IdentityServer4.Admin from skoruba yet so i cannot totally sure.

Comment: Your sample code says AddCookie("Cookies").  Will that overwrite the existing default identity server cookie?

Comment: my sample will override default aspnet cookie not IS4 cookie. If you want override IS4 cookie, just replace it with **IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme**.  It will override settings that you defined only